# Left-aligned title page in Beamer (Boadilla Usetheme)

Tags: horizontal-alignment

I would like **the title of my title page to be left-aligned**.
\flush{left} does not work. Any other commands which can do the trick?

```
 \documentclass{beamer}
 \usetheme{Boadilla} 
 \makeatother

  \title{ \textbf{Please help me}}
  \subtitle{I want this lines to be left aligned}
  \author{Thank you}
  \institute{Very Much!} 

  \begin{document}

  \begin{frame}
  \thispagestyle{empty}
  \titlepage
  \end{frame}

  \end{document}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want all text in title page left aligned, you need to introduce `left` option in `titlepage` template.

`Boadilla` uses `innertheme` shadow and from them, `titlepage` template looks like:

```
\setbeamertemplate{title page}[default][colsep=-4bp, rounded=true, 
      shadow=\beamer@themerounded@shadow]
```

you can introduce `left` in second optional set which is passed to corresponding `beamercolorbox`.

By the way, if you want to use an `empty` titlepage instead of `\thispagestyle{empty}` is more `beamer`-style to use `[plain]`.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Boadilla} 

\title{\textbf{Please help me}}
\subtitle{I want this lines to be left aligned}
\author{Thank you}
\institute{Very Much!} 

\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{title page}[default][left,colsep=-4bp,rounded=true,shadow=\beamer@themerounded@shadow]
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[plain]
%  \thispagestyle{empty}
   \titlepage
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]